# How do form Variable names by using defines in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

How to form the variable name using defines in  system verilog, actually i need to configure my registers (around 100). to do that i need to hardcode the 100 statement. is there any way to form a variable using define(anyother way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A typical use of Defines (or tick defines).

### Define

```
`define HIER2 testbench_top.hier1.hier2
```

### Usage

```
initial begin
  if( `HIER2.sub_component.wire == 1'b1)
```

### However

[SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Section 22.5.1 `define, covers text macros which can take arguments.

```
`define DISPLAY_MACRO1(a=1,b="A",c) $display(a,,b,,c);
`DISPLAY_MACRO1(4,5,6); 
// Expands to $display(4,,5,,6)
```

Arguments can be skipped to allow the default:

```
`DISPLAY_MACRO1( ,5,6); 
// Expands to $display(1,,5,,6)
```

The macros can also be used to create equations

```
 `define TOP(a,b) a + b
 a = `TOP(g ,h)
 // expanding to 
 // a = g + h
```

This is not directly useful for creating variable names because it requires spaces to delimit arguments, this is where the ``` `` ``` come in handy. They are used to delimit without using a space.

```
`define MAKE_REG( width, name) reg [ width -1:0] name``_register
`MAKE_REG( 4, enable) ;
//should expand to
//  reg [ 4 -1:0] enable_register ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to form an identifier in a `` `define `` is by using ``` `` ``` which joins tokens together into a single token

```
`define CONCAT(A, B) A``B

int `COCNCAT(X, Y); // defines an **int** XY
```

Sometimes you will see

```
`define myreg(name) \
  int _reg_``name;
```

So `` `myreg(0) `` declares `_reg_0`

There is no looping macro construct in SystemVerilog, so if you need `_reg_0`, `_reg_1`, ... you are better off declaring an array or using a generate statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
define myreg(name) \
  int _reg_``name;
```

So `myreg(0) declares _reg_0`

There is no looping macro construct in SystemVerilog, so if you need `_reg_0, _reg_1, ...` you are better off declaring an array or using a generate statement.

In the above statement,
please give clarification on how to use generate statement/array for `req_0,req_1...`